# Is it possible display the text in code snippet format dynamically using c# in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to display the question in the code format  which is taken from an xml file

```
<paper>
 <question>public class MyClass { public int x;public int y; public void Method(){ x=10;} }</question>
</paper>
```

In form.cs

```
XDocument doc=new XDocument();
doc.load(path of an xml file);
var questions=doc.descedants("question");
foreach( var ques in questions)
{
 label.Text=ques.Value;
}
 this.Controls.Add(label1);
```

It is displaying the output like

```
public class MyClass { public int x;public int y; public void Method(){ x=10;} }
```

But i need to display like this..what should i have to do

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int x;
  public int y;
  public void Method()
  { 
     x=10;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are pulling a string out of a file. Of course it'll print the same as before. As far as "is it possible," sure, if you want to write a code formatting library. Basically, without external libraries outside C# standards, you won't be able to get your code string in the desired format.

Comment: In order to achieve that what type of libraries I have to use

Comment: I don't have answers, nor am I going to do your research. Your keywords are "code" and "formatting". Good luck!

Comment: Just for nitpicking: the code as it appears in the XML is in a perfectly valid format for C#

Comment: s the code is in valid c# format

Answer (score 1):

Anusha,

Save it as a string:

```
string questions = doc.descedants("question");
```

Then define some delimiters:

```
char[] delim = { '{', '}', ';', ')' };
```

Then iterate through the string and handle each delimiter accordingly:

```
// You don't have to use StringBuilder, but it makes it easier to read.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Iterate through and handle each character in string.
int indentAmt = 0;
string indentStr = string.Empty;
foreach (char c in questions)
{
    // Determine the indent of the current line.
    indentStr = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < indentAmt; i++)
        indentStr += "    ";

    // Update the indent amount.
    if (c == '{')
        indentAmt++;
    else if (c == '}')
        indentAmt--;

    // Add a new line, plus the character, if the character is one of the delimiters.
    if (delimiters.Contains(c))
        sb.Append(c.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + indentStr);
    else
        sb.Append(c);
}

questions = sb.ToString(); // BOOM.
```

You can change the delimStr to have extra spaces in the beginning of the foreach loop if you want the indent to start with extra space.

EDIT: I fixed the indent problem.