# how to retrieve the code snippet from an xml file same as in original format using c# in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

In an xml file I stored code snippet but while retrieve that code from an xml file it is displaying in a single line what should i have to do in order to get output as same original

```
<paper>
<question>"public class MyClass 
          { 
            public int x;
            public int y; 
            public void   Method()
            {
              x=10;
            } 
          }"
</question>
</paper>
```

in form.cs

```
XDocument doc=new XDocument();
doc.load(path of an xml file);
var questions=doc.descedants("question");
foreach( var ques in questions)
{
label.Text=ques.Value;
}
this.Controls.Add(label1);
```

my output is

```
public class MyClass      { public int x;   public int y;   public void Method()   {    x=10;   }    }
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314820/is-it-possible-display-the-text-in-code-snippet-format-dynamically-using-c-sharp

Comment: No sir .... i'm the beginner to this c# and xml sir so please help me how to get back from this problem sir...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be wrapped in a [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) block. Code has way to many characters that overlap with XML markup and your line break problem will be fixed, too.